# Python virtual environment get deleted on HPC automatically

Tags: hpc

I run my training on HPC. I set up Python virtual environment for this. However, Python virtual environment gets deleted very often and I have to set it up again. I would appreciate if you would help to cure this. Setting up my Python virtual environment takes quite some time as I have to reinstall many packages and ...

Comment: You probably need to check the documentation for the HPC provider you are using, and verify where a virtual enviornment should be set up so that it persists.